# Creating multiple accounts with the same email

Tags: trello

I have two different organizations that I want to use Trello for, using the same email address or is it possible to have a username that is not an email address?

Answer (score 2):

I have figured this out - by using the Create Organization at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your email id. Try making another email id. It is not possible to use the same email id for two different user names.